# Does not work window.onload in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a pretty simple image switcher, which I use for manual images switcher and for carousel. In IE 8 it works strange. In carousel scenario image switches just once, thereafter it's dies. But (!) when I implemented Firebug Lite and try to trace - **it's works well, only with firebug on**... I tried some tricks, I found, but it's all to no purpose. I have no idea what caused this kind of behavior. How to fix it?

js

```
function toSlide(wrapper, options){
    var active = $('#' + wrapper + ' div.active');
    var slide;
    var direction;

    if (active.length === 0){
        active = $('#' + wrapper + ' div:last');
    }

    if (options === null) {
        options = {};
        options.reverse = false;
        options.animate = false;
    } else {
        options.reverse = options.reverse === null ? false : options.reverse;
        options.animate = options.animate === null ? false : options.animate;
    }

    direction = options.reverse === true ? active.prev() : active.next();

    slide = direction.length ? direction : $('#' + wrapper + ' div:first');

    if (options.animate === true){
        active.addClass('last-active');

        slide.addClass('active')
            .css({opacity:0.0})
            .animate({opacity:1.0}, 1000, function() {            
                active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
    } else {        
        slide.addClass('active');
        active.removeClass('active');
    }
}

function startSlideShow() {
    setInterval(function(){ toSlide('slideshow', {'animate': true}); }, 5000);
};

window.onload = function() {  
    if (document.location.pathname == '/'){startSlideShow();};
};
```

html in head

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]>  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection" />  <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> 
<script defer src="ie_onload.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery-1.6.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://fbug.googlecode.com/svn/lite/branches/firebug1.3/content/firebug-lite-dev.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

in bottom of html

```
<!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery. fall back to local if necessary -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- <script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/jquery-1.4.2.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script> -->

<!-- scripts concatenated and minified via ant build script-->
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/plugins.js"></script>
<script src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/script.js"></script>
<!-- end concatenated and minified scripts-->
```

Comment: Are you using `console.log` in your actual code that you've stripped out here?

Comment: Another good way to debug JavaScript in IE is to use Microsoft Script Debugger: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx. This will likely show you exactly which part of JavaScript is erroring. I agree with @I159 that it's quite likely to be `console.log`

Comment: @mVChr it sounds like you should add that as an answer. It might well be the solution.

Comment: I googled some and found it's window onload not works in IE. May be this is a cause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause was non-functional window.onload in IE8. I did right trick but made stupid mistake. So, I fixed it:

was

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
    <script defer src="ie_onload.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

is now

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]>  
    <script defer src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}js/ie_onload.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

in ie_onload.js

```
document.body.onload = function() {
    imageViewer();
    // and other functions
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Accessing `console` in FF without Firebug open or in IE will result in an error that will block the rest of your JS from executing.  If you want to leave calls to `console` in, you should implement them like one of the following:

```
try { console.log('blah'); } catch(e) {}
// or
if (typeof console != 'undefined') console.log('blah');
```

Or use a custom built logging function that implements something like the above.